# Can´t create Excel file on server

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am new to PHP. I want to create an Excel file. I have tried the code below.

```
<?php
    $loc= getcwd();
    require_once "Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php";

    $objTpl = new PHPExcel();
    $objTpl->setActiveSheetIndex(0); 
    $objTpl->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'URL');
    $objTpl->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1', 'No of post');
    $j=2;
if (!ini_get('safe_mode'))
{
    set_time_limit(0);
}
ini_set('memory_limit', '2700M');
error_reporting(0);
header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');

$filepath = 'csv/sample.csv';
require_once './File_CSV_DataSource.php';
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$csv = new File_CSV_DataSource;

 //$date=getdate();
 $objTpl->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(40);
 $objTpl->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(15);
 $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objTpl);

 echo $loc;
 $date = date('Y-m-d');
 $objWriter->save($loc.'/result/'.$date.'.xlsx');
    $objTpl->disconnectWorksheets();
    unset($objWriter, $objTpl);      ?>
```

The code works fine on my local machine, but not on my server. Why is it not working?

Comment: its server location is printing like this /home/cyberweb/public_html/csma

Comment: Check if you have the permission for write access on your server. You could make use of [`is_writable`](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php)

Comment: "not working" doesn't exactly tell us much. Have you done **ANY** basic debugging yourself? Maybe you forgot a library and one of your `require()` call is failing. maybe it's a permissions issue and you can't write the file on the server, blah blah blah...

Comment: @MarcB here how can i check whether its writable and whether it has write permision?

Comment: http://php.net/is_writeable

Comment: here the file name is assingning at the time of save before that I have to check na?? if(is_writable($objTpl)) whether its ok in my project. Im new to php Please help me

Comment: its because of the error Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in /home/cyberweb/public_html/csma/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php on line 205 how can i solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A prerequisite for PHPExcel is having the ZipArchive class enabled if you want to work with files that are zip compressed, such as xlsx or ods files.

If you don't have ZipArchive installed, then PHPExcel has a built-in alternative using PCLZip, though it's slower and more memory hungry. It's disabled by default, because ZipArchive is the preferred method, and should be available in most versions of PHP; but you can enable it using

```
PHPExcel_Settings::setZipClass(PHPExcel_Settings::PCLZIP);
```

before reading or saving any file that is zip-based